# Calling powershell from .Net Console application

Tags: c#, powershell

I have written a console application wherein I have called a powershell script from the console. In the powershell script I have written hello world as a return variable and it is running as expected but next time when I change the string from hello world to How are you it is not displaying the changed string. I cannot figure out myself what needs to be done to clear the pipeline or cache.
I have used the below namespace apart from default namespaces

```
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;



static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string _str = string.Empty;
            _str= RunScript(@"C:\Powershell_Scripts\Test.ps1");
Console.WriteLine("Input String is =" + str);
            Console.Read();
}

private static string RunScript(string scriptText)
        {
        // create Powershell runspace

        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        // open it
        runspace.Open();

        // create a pipeline and feed it the script text

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

        // add an extra command to transform the script
        // output objects into nicely formatted strings

        // remove this line to get the actual objects
        // that the script returns. For example, the script

        // "Get-Process" returns a collection
        // of System.Diagnostics.Process instances.

        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

        // execute the script

        Collection <PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
        pipeline.Streams.ClearStreams();
        // close the runspace

        runspace.Close();

        // convert the script result into a single string

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject obj in results)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Powershell Script i.e. Test1.ps1

```
    sleep 3
    $a=""
    $a = "Hello word"
    return $a
```

Comment: So, you change the string "Hello world" in your ps1 and run your C# app again, ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample how to use the PowerShell in a Runspace

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a runspace.
            using (Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
            {
                myRunSpace.Open();
                using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    // Create a pipeline with the Get-Command command.
                    powershell.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
                    powershell.AddScript(@"C:\Users\you\Desktop\a.ps1");
                    // add an extra command to transform the script output objects into nicely formatted strings
                    // remove this line to get the actual objects
                    powershell.AddCommand("Out-String");
                    // execute the script
                    var results = powershell.Invoke();
                    powershell.Streams.ClearStreams();
                    powershell.Commands.Clear();    
                    // convert the script result into a single string
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Further reference: [Creating a constrained runspace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn614668(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Sorry the same output is coming.. I think there is something which we are missing.

Comment: Not for me. What do you do exactly? I guess your sample does not reflect the real code you use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code which runs as expected

```
enter code here
try
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"c:\disk\op.txt") && (new FileInfo(@"c:\disk\op.txt").Length != 0))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Move(@"c:\disk\op.txt", @"c:\disk\Previous_op_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy hh mm") + ".txt");
                    log.Info("Previous Output File Successfully Renamed");
                }
                // TODO: Add delete logic here
                log.Info("Input ActionResult - Server " + Server);
                log.Info("Input ActionResult - Volume " + Volume);
                log.Info("Input ActionResult - Size " + size);
                string userID = "dir\\" + Session["Uname"].ToString();
                string userpassword = Session["Upwd"].ToString();
                log.Info("username " + userID);               
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                var con = new WSManConnectionInfo();
                log.Info("Pushing username  in PSCredential- " + userID.ToString().Trim());                
                con.Credential = new PSCredential(userID.ToString().Trim(), userpassword.ToString().Trim().ToSecureString());
                Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(con);
                runspace.Open();
                Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();                
                pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");               
                string _str = @"-Server " + Server + " -Volumeletter " + Volume + ": -deltasize " + size + " -Logfile c:\\disk\\op.txt -username " + userID + " -password " + userpassword;
                log.Info("Parameter string format- " + _str.Substring(0, _str.IndexOf("-password") + 9));
                pipeline.Commands.AddScript(@"C:\disk\diskerr.ps1 " + _str.ToString());
                pipeline.Commands[0].MergeMyResults(PipelineResultTypes.Error, PipelineResultTypes.Output);
                pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
                var results = pipeline.Invoke();
                runspace.Close();
                runspace.Dispose();
                foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                {
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
                    log.Info("Output from powershell: " + obj.ToString());
                }

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"c:\disk\op.txt") && (new FileInfo(@"c:\disk\op.txt").Length != 0))
                {
                    fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\test\op.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        _consoleOutput = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    _output = Regex.Replace(_consoleOutput, @"\r\n?|\n", "<br />");
                }

                return Content(_output);                
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Info("Error stackTrace inside Input ActionResult " + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                log.Info("Error Message inside Input ActionResult " + ex.Message.ToString());
                return View();
            }
```

You need to change the directory path and the powershell file name.